# Error 1130 connecting to MySQL on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, mysql, remote-access

I hope this is the right place for this...I currently am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 through VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host. I am trying to connect to the VM's MySQL engine using *MyDB Studio for MySQL*, and when I enter my MySQL login credentials, it gives me the following error back:

`Error 1130: Host '192.168.56.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

I am running the VM with Adapter 1 enabled for NAT, and Adapter 2 enabled for Host-only Adapter. `eth0 10.0.2.15` and `eth1 192.168.56.21`.

I can connect to Apache at `192.168.56.21`, and through PhpMyAdmin, everything works as it should. I did edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and commented out the line `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` by adding a `#` in front of it - I thought that this should have allowed remote connections.

Any ideas on how I can solve this? What could be wrong?

**EDIT:** I am trying to connect as 'root'.

**EDIT: SOLVED!!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this was such as silly oversight on my part, but the following 2 links pointed me in the right direction:

- http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/27/allow-remote-connections-to-your-mysql-server/
- [Port Forwarding to Connect to MySQL Database of VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12545/port-forwarding-to-connect-to-mysql-database-of-virtualbox)

So in the spirit of helping someone else out who might have the same problem...

I created a new user, granted him all privileges, and set the `host` to `%` to allow connections from any IP. Logged in with the new user, and voila! all good

Answer (score 10):

On your server run mysql from command line:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost -P 3306
```

Then run this command in mysql shell:

```
>use mysql
>GRANT ALL ON *.* to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Have a nice time.

Comment: May i ask you, what is the reason for this problem?